# HTML format to print on 8.5x11

Tags: html, printing

I have multiple sets of data and I would like them to look identical on individual 8.5x11 (standard size) sheets of paper. I am rendering them in HTML for printing by putting each set in an 8.5x11 div, but that div for some reason will always get cut off. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: The print area on an 8.5x11 is not 8.5x11. You should consider outputting to a PDF if you want real control over how it prints.